# Concatenate string and Pandas field in an apply lambda

Tags: python, pandas

I try to use/concatenate the value from a pandas field with a string in apply-lambda-endswith, but no success...

I explain, I have a df:

```
FieldA     FieldB
U          xxx-U.pdf
O          zzz-O.pdf
P          yyy-Q.pdf
```

I would like to get lines where the FieldB does not finish with *FieldA + .pdf*, so:

```
FieldA     FieldB
P          yyy-Q.pdf
```

Here my code:

```
NewDf = df[~df['FieldB'].apply(lambda x: x.endswith(df['FieldA'] + '.pdf'))]
```

I also tried this:

```
NewDf = df[~df['FieldB'].apply(lambda x: x.endswith(x['FieldA'] + '.pdf'))]
```

Or this:

```
NewDf = df[~df['FieldB'].apply(lambda x: x.endswith(x[0] + '.pdf'))]
```

But impossible...

Arrgggh! Any idea?

Comment: What do you have (dataframe) and what do you want?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hello, thank you, I edited my question, you will see an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to check if values in one column end with another. You can achieve that by calling apply on multiple columns.
Provided that `df` is:

```
   Field B Field A
0  1/a.pdf       a
1  2/b.pdf       b
2  3/b.pdf       c
3  4/c.pdf       d
```

You can apply some lambda along the axis 1

```py
df[['Field A', 'Field B']].apply(lambda item: item['Field A'].endswith(item['Field B'] + '.pdf'), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Edit: To have result in the form of dataframe, you can cast it like below

```py
result = df[['Field A', 'Field B']].apply(lambda item: item['Field A'].endswith(item['Field B'] + '.pdf'), axis=1)
result = pd.DataFrame(result) # You can add your optional params, column names for example
```

Comment: Hey, you right, it works fine, but I would get it in a dataframe, is it possible?

Comment: OK I understood, perfect! THX

Comment: I updated the answer to clarify. Mark the question as solved if my answer help.